# Loop in a template with index using Python3 Flask and Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I have an object with the following methods

`myobject.get_extension_count()`
`myobject.get_extension(index)`

With plain Python I could loop through like this

```
while i < cert.get_extension_count():
  print(cert.get_extension(i).get_short_name().decode("UTF-8"))
  print(cert.get_extension(i))
  i += 1
```

How can do such a loop in Jinja2 templates?

EDIT:
Based on proposal below I ended up with the following

```
<ul>
{%- for num in range(0, _cert.get_extension_count()) %}
  <li>
    {{ _cert1.get_extension(num).get_short_name().decode("UTF-8") }}:
    {{ _cert1.get_extension(num) }}
  </li>
{%- endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jinja2, you have the ability to do a for loop:

```
{% for var in list %}
  whatever it is you need to do
{% endfor %}
```

And then you could just use the range function, which is exactly what is available in Python:

```
{% for n in range(n) %}
```

That will count by 1. Might be a better choice than a while with increment, as the "for" does the increment automatically for you.